# Trying to store ID into a session after registering

Tags: c#, session, webforms, store, registration

I have a register form which check for the NRIC first, if the NRIC matches with the record in my patient table, it will sucessfully update that username and password into that existing record and it will redirect to the second image below. I want to store the patientID into the session after registering. The problem is the patientID that is stored is always patientID 1. See the below 1st image, if I type in S9583728F as the IC, and watever username and click sign up, it will redirect to the second image, I have used a textbox to check the value of the session, and it came out patientID 1 which belongs to richard!! It should be patientID 5 because the nric that I entered which is John belongs to patientID 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never execute the update query. And your select query is returning all patients so execute scaler will always give you this first one. You also might want to avoid so many cmd.execute..

Comment: How to excute the update query? and i deleted cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); since u said i have too many cmd.execute. Still it gives me patientID 1 for John @user3142116

Comment: I'm on a phone, so its difficult to write up a full answer, but you need to set your cmd text to the your variable called SQL and run cmd executenonquery on that. Your followup select statement needs a where clause to get the correct patient (where pid =@pid) Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks I try. Erm see my updated code, do u mean this when u said change to sql and run executenonquery? I am able to update now. Left the ID problem. And do u mean (where id =@id) or (where pIC =@pIC) ? @user3142116

Comment: I place my select statement after the line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();. Did i do that correct? how should be the select statement be? @user3142116

Comment: I think u meant by (where pIC =@pIC). I posted my answer, thanks it worked alr. @user3142116

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that works following user3142116 advice. Thanks

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;

    public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        Guid guid;
                        guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                        string sql = @"UPDATE patient 
                            SET 
                            pUserName = @pUserName,
                            pPassword = @pPassword
                            WHERE pIC = @pIC";

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtIC.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUsername", txtUsername.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", txtPassword.Value);

                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandText = sql;

                        con.Open();

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT patientID, pUsername, pPassword FROM patient WHERE pIC = @pIC;";

                        int id = (cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) : 0;
                        if (id > 0)
                        {

                            Session.Add("ID", id);

                            Session.Add("Username", txtUsername.Value);
                            Session.Add("Password", txtPassword.Value);
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, true);
                            Response.Redirect("registered.aspx");
                        }

                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```